# ¿Porque me sale este error al intentar instalar la plataforma android en cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org
2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org
2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

Ya tengo instalado el JDK , el SDK.

Comment: Hace poco tuve el mismo problema y lo solucioné desintalando el `JDK` y el `JRE` de nuevo (tenía una versión del `JDK` de 32 bits cuando mi PC tiene una arquitectura de 64), si googleas un poco encontrarás muchas otras causas y soluciones a este problema

Comment: necesitas aumentar el heap size del demonio de gradle, puedes pegar el build.gradle de tu módulo?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías tener instalado el **JDK, JRE y SDK Android** al final. Probablemente te falta el JRE. Otra cosa después de instalar ve a Archivos de programa y busca la carpeta de **BIN en el JDK FOLDER y JRE Folder**. (en cada uno entras al bin, copias la dirección ) y las **agregas a tu Variables de Entorno del Sistema**.

Le das  Path en la parte de abajo donde dice Variables de Sistema y editas el Path. (**poner ; después de la última dirección sino la tiene**) y con esto debería funcionar, puede sonar complicado. Si no puedes avísa y te ayudo! :)

P.D. Cualquier cosa con gusto!